# CSS: Is it possible to override one class with another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a template class, that is simply:

```
.template{
  display: none;    
}
```

This allows me to create a block with html that I can clone using jQuery and slightly edit to my liking.  However, one of the class I've been assigning to this same element to be cloned, sets:

```
.Category{
  display:table-row-group;
  //other properties not related to this problem not shown
}
```

This ends up overriding the template display property, which defeats the whole purpose of making it a template class.

Certainly I can always just add the Category class at the same time as I remove the template class via jQuery after cloning, but it's not ideal because the whole point is that the html should be easy to edit and changes can be made there instead of within jQuery code.

Thoughts?  I'm thinking maybe I can tell display to override other properties or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `display:none` to hide your templates. Instead, put them inside `<script type="text/x-template">` tags, or get more specific and use `text/x-handlebars` etc to define the actual type of template.

Comment: `display: none !important;`

Comment: Just to be clear, I'd like display:none to override any other display properties, which I would consider to be important.. once template is removed.

Comment: Oh, my bad.. I thought that !important.. meant "not important", similar to !=, meaning it would be overwritten.  That looks perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

CSS has a very well-defined order of priority.

If two selectors have the same priority (as per your two single-class selectors), then with all else being equal, the one which is defined last in the CSS code is the one that takes priority.

So the simple solution here is to move your template CSS to lower down your CSS code.

If you can't do that for whatever reason, your best option is to make the template selector more specific. For example, if all your template elements are contained inside a div element and you know that's always going to be true, you could change the selector to `div .template`. It is now more specific than the `.Category` selector, and should therefore take precedence.

Finally, you always have the option of `!important`. I try to avoid using it if possible, as it tends cause issues if overused, but it is there for cases where it's needed, and in fact, cases like this are about the best justified use-case for `!important` I can think of.

Answer (score 8):

That's exactly what `!important` does; add that to your value.

Comment: You can't add `!important` to a CSS Class as the question asked for.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options :

1. Recommended: The order of the class definition in the CSS really matters, be sure that the class you really want is after the other.
2. Not recommended: Use `!important` at the end of the sentence it is not recommended because if you need to override this after it's gonna be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Add !IMPORTANT to the .Category.

```
.Category{
  display:table-row-group;
  //other properties not related to this problem not shown
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution, you can simply make your css rule more specific:

```
body .Category{
  display:table-row-group;
 //other properties not related to this problem not shown
}
```

lets say you have this code :

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div{background-color:#ccc} 
    #content .Category{display:block;}
    .template{display:none;}
    .otherdiv{background-color:red;}
    body .otherdiv{background-color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="template Category" >inner template div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="template">outer template div</div>
  <div class="otherdiv">outer other div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `inner template div` will be displayed as bloc, but the outer will be not.

More specific your css rules are, more "naturally important" they are. In my code, the div `.otherdiv` will be displayed with a green backgroupd because the `body .otherdiv` is more important than `.otherdiv`

See that article about css specificity http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

"Start at 0, add 1000 for style attribute, add 100 for each ID, add 10 for each attribute, class or pseudo-class, add 1 for each element name or pseudo-element."

using `!important` is not recommended at all, and is not supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
.template.Category {
  display: none;
}
```

Or just use !important

```
.template {
  display: none !important;
}
```